# Quadratic forms linearized by real matrices

Tags: quadratic-forms

Could you please tell me what is meant by this:
quadratic forms linearized by real matrices

I don't ask you to explain it, just simply tell me what is meant with it. Diagonalization or such? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(x, y)$ is a scalar product on a vector space, and $A$ a linear transformation on that space, then the mapping that takes $x$ to $(Ax, x)$ is called a quadratic form, and is said to be realized by $A$.

Comment: So 'linearized' and 'realized' is the same?

Comment: Sorry, no.  "Linearized" mean "approximated by its first two Taylor terms."  For a quadratic form $q(x) = (Ax, x)$, this would be:
$$
q(x) \sim q(0) + {d \over dx} (Ax, x) = (A \cdot, x) + (Ax, \cdot).
$$